# Buttons and getElementsByName to find value

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a group of buttons like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_1" name="height" value="1" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()">14,5</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_2" name="height" value="2" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()">29,0</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_3" name="height" value="3" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()">43,5</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_4" name="height" value="4" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()">58,0</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_5" name="height" value="5" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()">72,5</button>
</div>
```

I have been trying to find the value of the selected button with:

```
document.getElementsByName('aantal_planken')[0].value = document.getElementsByName('height')[0].value;
```

but this always echoing the value of the first button instead of the selected button.
How to get the value of the selected button?

Comment: And why cant you use document.getElementByID('ID'); ????

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('height')[0]` — it's first button, look at its index 0.

Comment: @Nevermore then I need for each button a separate code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass clicked button reference as `this` in validate function and then use it to get the clicked button value as follows -

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_1" name="height" value="1" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate(this)" onclick="validate(this)">14,5</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_2" name="height" value="2" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate(this)" onclick="validate(this)">29,0</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_3" name="height" value="3" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate(this)" onclick="validate(this)">43,5</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_4" name="height" value="4" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate(this)" onclick="validate(this)">58,0</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="height_5" name="height" value="5" data-preview="preview_hl_height" onkeyup="validate(this)" onclick="validate(this)">72,5</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(ele) {
    console.log(ele.value);
    console.log(ele.innerText);
}
</script>
```